# asp.net mvc3, why do I need to constructors for my controller class

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, inversion-of-control

I am learning asp.net mvc3.  one example I found online is to show me how to use IOC.

```
            public class HomeController : Controller
            {
                private IHelloService _service;
                public HomeController():this(new HelloService())
                {}

                public HomeController(IHelloService service)
                {
                    _service = service;
                }
            }
```

there are two constructors in this example. I understand the second one.  the first one I understand what that for, but to me, it seems like extra code, you will never need it.

can someone please explain to me whats the point to add the first constructor.

```
                public HomeController():this(new HelloService())
                {}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the MVC Framework instantiates a controller, it uses the default (parameter-less) constructor.

By default, you are injecting a concrete `IHelloService` implementation. This will be used when a user navigates to the action.

Unit Tests would use the overload and pass in the mock `IHelloService` implementation rather than calling the default constructor.

Answer (score 3):

It can be useful if you don't use a dependency injection framework that injects this for you. In this way you never have to manually inject the object, the object will handle that by itself.

The second constructor is, of course, useful to inject custom objects when unit testing.

Normally one would need to do this:

```
IFoo foo = new Foo();
IBar bar = new Bar(foo);
```

When your constructor creates a default object you can just do this:

```
IBar bar = new Bar();
```

Bar will then create a Foo and inject it into itself.